# Snubber on the line or just the inductor

Tags: transmission-line, snubber

A document on the public internet, yet apparently covered by NDA, makes a surprising claim about snubbers.  [vendor link](https://www.hidglobal.com/sites/default/files/resource_files/plt-02139_a.0_nas_products_installation_precautions.pdf) or [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20180427055822/https://www.hidglobal.com/sites/default/files/resource_files/plt-02139_a.0_nas_products_installation_precautions.pdf)

Page 12 shows a device powering and switching an inductive DC load.

similar to this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2freVWM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The text claims that the diode is more effective if located close to the load
(A) but how can that be? By putting is closer to the source (B) is also snubs the inductance of the cable connecting the source to the load.

So is there a reason to put the diode at the far end? (other than the likelihood that someone want to add an additional switch near the load (location C)

I built a similar circuit to what they described once  and the diode near the load didn't offer sufficient snubbing to protect other electronics that was sharing the same cable. I had to put the diode at the relay end of the cable to get the electronics to survive the switching transients. I was using CAT-5e cable with two pairs for switched power and the other two pairs for power and data to the electronics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I found in the document that relates to your question: -

> To minimize the antenna-like radiation of this electromagnetic energy
>   from wires connected to the inductor, the flyback diode should be
>   connected as physically close to the inductor as practicable. This
>   approach also minimizes those parts of the circuit that are subject to
>   an unwanted high-voltage.

And that is perfectly true (see page 6 of the first document).

On page 12 it says this: -

> The recommended and most effective position for the diode is at the
>   inductive load itself, if this is not possible the diode will still
>   help suppress the voltage spike even if placed at the HID NAS product
>   connector.

I do not see a contradiction here.

Comment: first quote is accurate, but incorrect - when the switch opens the current in the loop stops abruptly. with a diode near the switch the stopping is slower. so radiation is less. second quote:  My argument is that they have this backwards.

Comment: @Jasen I'm afraid you are wrong - the current in the loop cannot stop abruptly. If it did, then infinite volts would be generated (V = L di/dt). To minimize EM radiation you want the current to fall to zero in as long a time as possible in order to minimize di/dt and hence reduce radiation. The further you place the diode from the inductor the more the wires radiate. You are, unfortunately misled.

Comment: how do you get from your first sentence to that conclusion?  Think about what happens when the relay contact open.

Comment: Which bit do you not understand?

Comment: with the diode distant from the the switch when the contacts open the current flowing in the loop between the switch and the diode stops abruptly, how can that be better than a gradual stopping then the diode is near the switch?

Comment: OK I understand where you are coming from. Yes, with the diode at the inductor then the current in the wires feeding the coil stops abruptly and of course this creates an impulse of EM radiation if the wires feeding the inductor were not twisted or coax. However, the inductor has stored energy in its mag field and this can resonate with the wire capacitance and produce a worse EM effect than just the feed current stopping.

Comment: resonate really?

Comment: Just consider the amount of energy in a solenoid. If it's 1 henry and is taking an amp that's 500 mJ. If this gets released in 1 ms that's the equivalent power of 500 watts. The 12 volt supply driving 1 amp is only 12 watts so turning that off abruptly is incosequential by comparison. And yes, the line capacitance and diode inductance could form a very sharp resonant tuned circuit. A diode at the solenoid causes the energy to be released much more slowly from the magnetic field and hence the rate of change of energy (power) is much smaller and can't produce EMI that is anywhere near as great.

Comment: why would it be released so fast? there's a diode.  You turn off the switch and the current starts flowing the tough the diode, to the rest of the circuit it just looks like the input voltage changed from +12V to -0.7V,  there's going to be a reflection at the end of the line but that's going the be less than 12V typically.

Comment: I think I've answered my own question... it's a transmission line,

Comment: still tryingt to picture exactly what happens, tried and failed to simulate.

Comment: With the diode at the power source end you will get transmission line problems i.e. reflections. You want to avoid those so you keep the diode at the inductor end else you get an edge of voltage sent back up the wire and that voltage is determined by \$Z_0\$. If it were taking 1 amp this would form 50 volts if \$Z_0\$ is 50 ohms and it would hurtle back up the line only to be reflected back.

Comment: I see what you mean by resonate, the line will ring like an organ pipe

Answer (score 2):

When you switch off a high value inductor, it dumps a reverse charge back into the circuit. The best place for a snubber diode is at the coil/inductor, however it still allows about -1 volts to come back to the source.

You can insert a 10 ohm resistor in series at point 'C' to help trap the back-emf at the inductor. A 1uF capacitor rated for 50% above the inductor voltage will absorb even more of the back-emf.

It is all about time, because in a short period of time the energy has completely dissipated. The key is to 'buy' some time with diodes, resistors and capacitors so the back-emf goes to zero volts before doing any harm.

You may consider using a Schottky diode like the 1N5822 at the inductor and the power source as it only allows a reverse voltage of about 0.6 volts.

If you have sensitive electronics to protect **don't fret over having protection at both ends of the line**, and a 10 ohm dampening resistor in the middle. These parts are cheap compared to the cost of what they are protecting.

Comment: sensitive - well there's microcontroller in there somewhere under the black goop. the signaling was RS232 so fairly rugged,

Comment: In your first sentence you talk of "reverse charge". Can you be clearer about what you mean?

Comment: @Andyaka. 'Charge' was not the proper word. A reverse voltage would have been better, considering what the snubber diode is for.

Comment: And what about the -1 volt you mention?

Comment: It is 6 am and I am just going to bed. Answer later.

Comment: -1 volt is probably diode drop (eg: 1n4001 @ 1A) but that 10 ohm resistor is not going to work well.

Comment: @Jasen. Thanks for having a brain. Yes there would be a 1 volt back-emf going down the line. How much is reflected is but a guess. That is why I told the OP: "don't fret over having protection at both ends of the line." This is being reviewed by moderators. I expect to hear from them soon.